# How to ensure a generic function passed to a higher order function has void return type?

Tags: typescript

```
function higherOrderFunction<P extends any[], R>(anyFunction: (...a: P) => R) {
  return (...args: P) => {
    anyFunction(...args); // anyFunction = lowerOrderFunction
  };
}

function lowerOrderFunction(name: string) {
  return '';
}

const higherOrderFunctionWithLowerOrderFunction = higherOrderFunction(lowerOrderFunction);
higherOrderFunctionWithLowerOrderFunction('x');
```

**How to ensure `anyFunction` will have `void` type**?

This must be for a **generic function** (generic means "any function" here) passed to higherOrderFunction, not just the example `lowerOrderFunction` above for which is enough to add `:void`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't want you to do this, see [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void).  A function that returns a non-`void` value can be used wherever a `void`-returning function is needed.  In TypeScript, a `void` return type means "you should not try to use the return value of this function" and not "this function really doesn't return a value".  So the most conventional answer to this question is that you should not need to enforce such a restriction; if `anyFunction` returns a value, it will be ignored, which should be fine.

---

If you really want to bend the rules so that TypeScript will enforce the restriction, one thing you can do is this:

```
function higherOrderFunction<P extends any[]>(anyFunction: (...a: P) => undefined | void) {
  return (...args: P) => { anyFunction(...args); };
}
```

By specifying `undefined | void` you are saying you'll accept an `undefined` return value (which should be okay, right?) or otherwise a function that doesn't return (using `void` in a union seems to circumvent the compiler's "any value is fine" logic here):

```
higherOrderFunction(() => 1); // error, number is not undefined
higherOrderFunction(() => undefined); // okay
higherOrderFunction(() => console.log("this is void returning")); // okay
```

Or, if you want to make the compiler reject even `undefined`-returning functions, you could use a generic signature that infers return type and then makes things not work unless the type it infers is `void`:

```
function higherOrderFunction<P extends any[], R>(
  anyFunction: (...a: P) => R & (void extends R ? void : never)
) {
  return (...args: P) => { anyFunction(...args); };
}
```

The type `(void extends R ? void : never)` evaluates to `void` if `R` is `void`, and `never` otherwise.  So you get this behavior:

```
higherOrderFunction(() => 1); // error, number is not never
higherOrderFunction(() => undefined); // error, undefined is not never
higherOrderFunction(() => console.log("this is void returning")); // okay
```

---

Those methods "work" in that they enforce the restriction for the example use case, but there are likely to be edge cases.  The most obvious edge case is that the following code has nothing to do with `higherOrderFunction` and will not generate a warning:

```
const thisIsAllowed: () => void = () => 1; // okay
```

After all, non-void-returning functions are assignable to void-returning functions.  And now the compiler sees `thisIsAllowed` as a `void`-returning function; it has forgotten all about the `1`.

And so, no matter how `higherOrderFunction()` is defined so as to "require" a `void` return, there will be no error here:

```
higherOrderFunction(thisIsAllowed); // no error
```

That might be a deal-breaker for you, depending on your use case.

---

I think the best thing to do here is probably to embrace TypeScript's viewpoint that a `void` return type means "ignore any value returned" and not "no value is returned", and move on.  Maybe the above rule-bending methods will still be of some use to you, but you shouldn't rely on them to prohibit functions that return values.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=3.9.2#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-LnA0FdozEverxGFo-l9H5B2n16ui9fT9ITkW8QUYaBu0IJ94zJV9Dy1VBpTpBkmVZa0AWoOteTqQdBWFR1xW8SUENpOUOVtVU1lwTUDUw5Z4KNKDSQRa5Bmtcj7QqH8nRdN0PWAXYgA)

Comment: Very well put. It's worth noting that there is no such thing is a JavaScript function that does not return a value, which I think validates the "should not use" meaning

Comment: I fully agree with you @jcalz. great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

just change the return type of anyFunction passed on parameters

```
function higherOrderFunction<P extends any[], R>(anyFunction: (...a: P) => void) {
    return (...args: P) => {
      anyFunction(...args); // anyFunction = lowerOrderFunction
    };
  }
  
  function lowerOrderFunction(name: string) {
    return '';
  }
  
  const higherOrderFunctionWithLowerOrderFunction = higherOrderFunction(lowerOrderFunction);
  higherOrderFunctionWithLowerOrderFunction('x');
```

Comment: this won't prevent returning a non-void type from `lowerOrderFunction` (or any function passed to `higherOrderFunction` to that regard)

Comment: You cannot check this at run time if that is what you mean. The only thing you can do is not to use the returned value.